# How to implement screen sharing and viewing in ASP.Net Core by using SignalR?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, blazor

I am doing a project in ASP.Net Core and Blazor Server App. There is a particular page or a component which happens to be confidential and hence this page is shown to the clients only after entering a OTP, and eventually, the Admin user requires to view the screen of the client's computer while working on this form.
Can this be implemented (Screen sharing of the remote computer and Viewing by the admin) by using SignalR alone ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is unclear. Blazor Server already uses SignalR, the client already views the web app on the browser using components. What does `view the screen of the client computer while using a particular view (component)` mean? Do you want ClientA to view clientB's browser display like a monitor ? Or do you want a component to impersonate another user? That would be a *completely* different problem.

Comment: Hi there! thanks. I have rephrased this.

Comment: Please go through this article
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/screencastr-simple-screen-sharing-app-using-signalr-streaming/

Comment: Yes, you can do that with SignalR. Note that in Blazor Server App, the client side (browser) communicate with the server side via SignalR. You can either employ that connection (Circuit) or (easier and better, I guess) create a new connection and a hub object dedicated for your current requested task.